# Making a toroidal array in C# (console) for my Conway's game of life, need a little help

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey there, the way my program works so far is...

I have a class called Grid, so far this works, 
Grid contains a member, 'board' which is a 2D array of bools.
I manage to load values from a file into the grid fine, 
in fact I manage to preform Conway's life iterations just fine,
however the program behaves as if the cells outside the grid are dead (not toroidal)

here's the code (C#) for the member of Grid which I use to find neighbours:

```
        public bool Peek(int Horz, int Vert)
    {
        int X = x + Horz, Y = y + Vert;
        if (X < 0)
            X = width - 1;
        else if (X > width - 1)
            X = 0;
        if (Y < 0)
            Y = height - 1;
        else if (Y > height - 1)
            Y = 0;
        return board[X, Y];
    }
```

this appears to be where the problem is,
Horz and Vert are defining the relative position in the array 'board'
x and y are the 'current position' members of the Class Grid.

I just can't see what's wrong, It should be in here.

in case you need it here is the code (in Program.Main) that counts neighbours

```
int neighbours = 0;
                for (i = -1; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if (grid.Peek(i, -1))
                        neighbours++;
                    if (grid.Peek(i, 1))
                        neighbours++;
                }
                if (grid.Peek(-1, 0))
                    neighbours++;
                if (grid.Peek(1, 0))
                    neighbours++;
                if (grid.Cell)
                {
                    if (neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3)
                        next.Cell = true;
                    else next.Cell = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (neighbours == 3)
                        next.Cell = true;
                    else next.Cell = false;
                }
```

the value of grid.Cell (grid being an instance of Grid) is the same as grid.Peek(0, 0) and then the x and y positions in the grid object move to the next cell. (as part of the get and set methods)

Comment: Code seems fine to me. Are you sure said cells are not dead? How are you testing this? If you drop a [glider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(Conway%27s_Life)) on the board does it go round and round?

Comment: The file that I'm using as input has a glider in it, it loads perfectly fine and the glider moves but it 'hits' the wall and becomes a 2x2 block (still-life) as if the top of the board doesn't notice that the bottom of the board has a glider touching it at all.

Comment: Check that your member never has coordinates like (width, width) or (-1, -1) etc.

Comment: If I access an array[-1,-1] C# would throw an exception, (using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express) and it would be quite obvious if it was thrown. But good suggestion anyways, I understand that C wouldn't(afaik).

Comment: Which wall your glider hits? Top, left, bottom or right?

Comment: moves from about the centre (from the starting file), diagonally down-right, and hits the bottom wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> x and y are the 'current position' members of the Class Grid.

I don't see a bug in the code snippet but this statement raises a Big Red Flag.  The grid doesn't have a current position, only a Cell does.  You cannot keep track of the 'next.Cell' state for the grid, it must be computed for each individual cell.  The *next* grid is created from the new cells *after* evaluating all the grid positions.  Or use two grids and swap them.

Comment: next is an instance of Grid, grid is an instance of grid;
it finds the next ones and then adds them onto the 'next' grid NOT the current grid :P maybe I should have mentioned that the variables are non-static? thanks for the advice though...

Comment: Does that make sense?  How can a grid have a bool Cell property?  One cell?

Comment: Your answer was as close to the right answer as we were going to get with the information given, so thanks, reviewing how my next state became my 'this' state fixed the problem good and proper.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your object's coordinates (both x and y) never have a value below 0 or above width-1 or height-1, because your Peek code won't handle such situations properly. I would also recommend to rewrite the method to be more flexible:

```
public bool Peek(int Horz, int Vert)
{
    int X = x + Horz, Y = y + Vert;
    if (X < 0)
        X += width;
    else if (X > width - 1)
        X -= width;
    if (Y < 0)
        Y += height;
    else if (Y > height - 1)
        Y -= height;
    return board[X, Y];
}
```

In this case even cell with coordinates x=-1, y=height+2 will work fine.

Comment: I would throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if Horz or Vert are outside the range [-1,1]. That would mean a bug somewhere else, so I'd prefer to fail than to go on as if everything is ok.

Comment: Works the same, but I can't see anything wrong with it.  Also I'm not so sure your code is any more flexible, although it looks cleaner so I'm keeping it in.

Comment: adding the lines

            if (Horz < -1 || Horz > 1 || Vert < -1 || Vert > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what's wrong with my program and it has nothing to do with the grid thing, when I wanted to make grid = next, I typed grid = next -sigh- and of course that just made them become the same instance of the same class... now I just need to figure out how to update the board.. :P apparently it was just coincidence that the glider died where it did.

```
            grid = next;
            grid.Draw();
```

^failure^

Comment: **FIXED** with a simple do{}while loop